# How to parse 1,2,3 string to int with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I need to make a variable like `1(int),(coma)2(int),(coma)` so on.. from a string `1,2,3` 
and it is a parameter of a function that is place within

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN ([that string]);
```

with `PDO` prepare statement.

I tried to explode it and then make another variable but still thats STRING I need 1`(int),(coma)2(int),(coma)` NOT string because STRING doesn't work here

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN ([that string]);
```

Comment: That's a common issue. Converting the string does not help, as the `IN` clause needs a list of values. PDO itself however cannot bind arrays. You need one of the manual workarounds for generating `?,?,?` and list unpacking.

Comment: In English,  "i" is always capitalized :)

Comment: but how @mario?
can you please show me exact why how to do that ?

Comment: @user3881924 Well I'm using something pre-made instead of tedious workarounds. [`db("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (??)", $id_list)`](http://fossil.include-once.org/hybrid7/wiki/db) for example expands `??` into bound args according to the passed list.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, `IN('1,2,3')` is not the same predicate as `IN(1,2,3)`. So you can't just use a single string.

If you are 100% sure that the string contains integers and there is no chance it contains other input (for example if your code created the string from values that are sure to be integers), then you could simply interpolate the list into your query.

But I prefer to use prepared statements when there's no guarantee that the string contains *only* integers.

You can make a prepared statement that has as many parameters as the count of elements in your list.

```
function afunc($string)
{
  $array_of_values = explode(",", $string);
  $array_of_placeholders = array_fill(1, count($values), "?");
  $string_of_placeholders = implode(",", $array_of_placeholders);
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN ($string_of_placeholders)";
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->execute($array_of_values);
}
```

MySQL doesn't care if the parameter value is a string or an integer. Even if you use `bindParam($variable, PDO::PARAM_INT)` if you read the code for the PDO_mysql driver, the type arguments like `PDO::PARAM_INT` are ignored, and all parameters are passed to the MySQL server as strings. Since they are in an integer-comparison context, the SQL parser converts them to integers (and strips any non-numeric part).

Comment: wait, are you inserting an array to WHERE id IN ([array]) ?

Comment: I used `implode()` to turn the array of placeholders into a comma-separated string. I'll edit to show that more clearly.

Answer (score -1):

You can use :

```
$i = 1;
$y = 2;

$q = $i . "," . $y;

SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN ($q);
```

You can use . Operator in order to connect strings.

Comment: Why it is a downvote? I even wrote it from mobile and trying to help. Wht is the problem here?

Comment: Because this: "It is not important whether it is int or atring your are trying to concat, php handles the rest" is horrid advice that can lead to SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
$array[$key] = intval( $value );
```

This will parse the string into an integer. See [intval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php)

Comment: It's not untrue, it just has nothing whatsoever to do with the question.

Comment: @Boann How doesn't it? He needs to find an `ID` with an integer value. He said he exploded the string but that still resulted in a string value. This is how he can parse it into an integer.